# need help on getting a value from "{"k1":"v1", "k2":"v2"}"

Tags: javascript, attributes

i got a result from someone else code

```
elem.getAttribute("additional-attributes")
```

...the result is like:

```
"{"k1":"v1", "k2":"v2"}"
```

so do I have to parse the string to get "v2" from "k2"? or are there better ways to get the value?

Thanks!

Comment: The "string" (I'm assuming you've quoted it incorrectly and it's actually `'{"k1":"v1", "k2":"v2"}'`) is in the JSON format and represents a JS object.

Comment: maybe you are right... i saw the string from a firefox watch... if so, how should i get the value? thanks!

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` to get the object, and then `obj.k1` or `obj.k2` to get the values...

Comment: wow this works! I do not know how to support ur comment as the answer though... thanks a lot!

Comment: @user723979 I've made it an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you want to use `JSON.parse` to get the object, and then `obj.k1` or `obj.k2` to get the values...

Answer (score 0):

You could just split on comma then colon. Or a simple regex could do the trick.

Comment: ...if parsing is the only way...i guess i have to then... i m thinking there was something wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

If the string is like this actually (note the ' as a string operator):

```
var string = '{"k1":"v1", "k2":"v2"}'
```

You can do this (to convert that string into JS object):

```
var obj = eval("("+string+")");
```

And then to access `k2` value do this:

```
var k2value = obj.k2;
```

If the string is badly formated, you can reformat it so it is valid JS string, and then do the eval() on it to make it an object.

Comment: +1 for a method that works in a browser without native JSON support (introduced in ES5).

Comment: @Saxoier: I am not "parsing" JSON "with eval" I am using eval for its purpose, and thats EVALUATION, because eval is used for "EVALUATION OR EXECUTION OF THE GIVEN JAVASCRIPT EXPRESSION". This is how it was done in the old days when there was no native JSON support in web browsers, and it works anywhere, and since its result is put in a new VAR, no one can't inject JavaScript that would be unwillingly executed. So I don't see why you -1 me, can you clarify whats so bad about the eval?

Comment: @RobG: 'eval' is the only built-in method - You can always write your own JSON-Parser or use a already available JSON-lib.

Comment: @Saxoier - I don't understand your comment directed at me. There is certainly no need to write a JSON parser to turn text into an object and it's pretty simple to write a function to generate JSON from an object (but that wasn't the question).